# Building a contact form in Umbraco 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco7

I´m new to MVC, and I have followed a tutorial for building a contact form page but get this error message: namespace name 'Models' does not exist

Controller - ContactSurfaceController.cs

```
namespace test.Controllers {
public class ContactSurfaceController : SurfaceController

{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(ContactModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendFormat("<p>Meddelande: {0}</p>", model.Message);
            sb.AppendFormat("<p>Namn: {0}</p>", model.Name);
            sb.AppendFormat("<p>E-post: {0}</p>", model.Email);
            sb.AppendFormat("<p>Telefon: {0}</p>", model.Phone);

            library.SendMail("noreply@test.se", "info@test.se", model.Subject, sb.ToString(), true);

            return RedirectToUmbracoPage(model.ThankYouPage);
        }
        return CurrentUmbracoPage();
    }


} 
}
```

Model - ContactModel.cs

```
namespace test.Models
{
    public class ContactModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Ärende")]
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Namn")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("E-post")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Telefon")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Ärende")]
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public int ThankYouPage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Partial View - ContactForm.cshtml

```
@model test.Models.ContactModel

@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("Contact", "ContactSurface", null, new {@class = "contact-form" }))
{ 
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div>

        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Subject)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Subject)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Subject)

        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Message)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Message)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Message)

        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)

        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Phone)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Phone)

        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email)

        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ThankYouPage)

    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Skicka" class="btn-accept" />
}
```

And it´s here I get the error message on the first line
View - Contact.cshtml

```
@using test.Models
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage

@{
    Layout = "uBlogsyBaseSite.cshtml";
}

@Html.Partial("ContactForm", new ContactModel { ThankYouPage = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<int>("thankYouPage") })
```

What have I missed?

I really need help with this, any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Jonas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where do you store your surface controller code and your model code?

It should be stored in the app_code or in a separate DLL.

Comment: I´m store it in the Controllers and Models folder. But that should not cause the error message, or?

Comment: Yes, it DOES cause the error message.  If stored in "controllers" and "models" folder, you should BUILD them appropriatly using visual studio or msbuild.  But you have probably, have a "website" configured.  And websites do not compile files outside the app_data.